# Bash script too slow as string variable grows

Tags: bash, variables, mbox

The input file ($1) is a mbox file (which is a text file).
The idea is to read it from the beginning, save a message in $message, do something with it, discard it and start all over again.
The problem now is that the more the message is large and the more the script slows down.
The script always hangs when it reaches a 10mb message, which I calculated it would take at least 20 minutes.

```
message=''
IFS_old=$IFS
IFS=''
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^From\ .* ]]; then
        message="$line"
    else
        message+=$'\n'"$line"
    fi
done < "$1"
IFS=$IFS_old
```

You just comment the line

```
message+=$'\n'"$line"
```

and in one minute the script finishes with a 120mb mbox file.
Is it bad to expect a variable to hold few mb?
Thank you all

Comment: Have you tried using an array of lines and concatenating at the end instead of doing the concat during the loop? Also you can just set `IFS` on the `read` and not need to save and restore it (and have it modified for other commands in the meanwhile): `while IFS= read -r line; do`.

Comment: `bash` really isn't the right language for this type of processing.

Comment: and please confirm that your `echo "new message starts at line: $line_number"` is just a place holder for more complex processing that you want to do. If you just want to print that message, you can do it in a one line `awk` script. Be sure to **edit your question** with this info, rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Comment: "Is it bad to expect a variable to hold few mb?" Yes, yes it is.

Comment: Don't reimplement procmail.

Comment: Yes Etan, it worked! Just processed the file in 5 minutes. Still a long time and cpu to the ceiling. I wonder how Thunderbird compacts folders so smoothly, maybe  Chepner comment explains it. Any recommendation for a smoother script? Yes Shellter the echo was just for debug.

Comment: `mapfile` may help enhance @EtanReisner's strategy.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, do you recommend to write each message on disk before processing it? I thought ram was faster

Comment: "ram" versus "disk" ignores many details of how the contents are gathered and manipulated.